# should i chmod files after upload in php?

Tags: php

I'm uploading files to the server with a PHP Script. I also have scripts to let the user delete these files. Should I chmod the file after upload to give user the rights to delete the file ?

```
chmod ($baseDir . $_FILES['file']['name'], 0644);
```

Comment: Depends on your needs.  What are they uploading?  Where are you putting it?  Why do they have real accounts on your server?

Comment: They are uploading images, documents, video files. I'm putting it under a folder in my doc root (public_html). This folder has permissions 755.

Comment: What you are doing is extremely insecure.  Unless this is locked down well, and for your own use only, you are wide open to all sorts of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: You mean it's insecure to have the folder with 755 permissions ? How will I read files from the directory though ?

Comment: You're letting anyone upload whatever they want to your server.  What happens when they upload `something-evil.php`?  Then they can access it from the web, running arbitrary code on your server.  Always keep user uploads out of the doc root, and use a file name that you generate with no file extension.  As you need those files, load them with `read_file()` or equivalent, and set the content type header.  You can also set a `content-disposition` header to specify the original file name.  The point is, don't give users control over your web server!  Your storage system should be transparent.

Comment: Well, problem is I need to have the files in docroot as I have a wysiwyg (ckeditor) with the pdw file browser which it seems can only access files that are in the docroot. Would a 700 permission on the images folder be safer ?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, no. If the uploading script and the deleting script run as the same system user, it already has the permissions to delete it.

Just try uploading a file, and then delete it?